# How to convert date YYYYMMDD to YY-MM-DD in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a date column which is in YYYYMMDD or 20120101 format. This is because SAP stores it in this format, so cannot change this.

How can I convert this to a YYYY-MM-DD format in a MySQL query? In DB2, I used a to_date() function.

In MySQL, I'm trying the STR_TO_STRING() function but it returns 'null'.

```
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE(VBAP.ERDAT,'%Y-%m-%d') FROM VBAP
```

Comment: Why is your date column in a "format" at all? Why isn't it just a `DATE` type, which you'd query using parameterized SQL and avoiding conversions to string in the first place?

Comment: Cause this is how SAP stores it in DB2, unfortunately.

Comment: When you have a constraint like that where a better solution would be obvious if you *weren't* constrained, it's worth explaining that constraint in the question.

Comment: Alright, I thought mentioning that the existing format is in this way was enough. Updated my question.

Comment: ha. just came across this... SAP as well. *shakes fist* :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works..

```
date_format(str_to_date(VBAP.ERDAT, '%Y%m%d'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```